# Disable mobile version only for particular devices (SP Online)

Tags: master-page, device-channel, mobile-view

Can I disable mobile view only for iPad and iPhone (IOS) devices (users with other devices should still use mobile version)?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using Device Channels - it allows you to set a 'profile' for a given mobile device (using the user agent string), and set options against it, such as the Master Page that will be used. Take a look at Option 3 on https://academy.bindtuning.com/deactivate-sharepoint-2013-mobile-view for a start.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thank You for response! I've already red this article, but as I understand I need to disable 'Mobile View' feature in this case? I still need mobile view for other clients (with non-IOS devices)

Comment: I'm not an expert on master pages so I'm not sure - I imagine mobile view uses a separate master page than the standard one. I would try it and see if it still implements mobile view as something 'on top' of the master page (i.e. the choice of MP doesnt matter as long as the feature is on).

Comment: A messy solution would be to redirect any users with the given user agent string to a separate site which shows the same data, but doesn't have Mobile View feature enabled... but I think that would become a headache later on unless you could link in all the required data static and never need the users to directly navigate to the site where it actually sits inside.

Comment: Hi Thomas! Don't want to disable mobile view, think other users could have problems. There is the way to programmatically redirect user to specific master page, but as far as I understand it uses ASP.NET server-side features, which is not available in cloud.. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43377/SharePoint-Dynamically-Change-Master-Page.aspx

Comment: You need to test first of all whether using the Device Channel to redirect Apple devices to a custom Master Page (i.e. NOT one for mobile use) over-rides Mobile View - I don't know if it does.
If it does, then the only other option I can think of is to redirect them to a master page in a different site (if that's even possible) where Mobile View is turned off.

Comment: Another option is to put some Javascript in the master page that detects the User Agent string and redirects appropriatley, but again not sure as to feasibility of that.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was simpler.

In the RouteConfig.vb/cs file change the RedirectMode to off in the third line of code. Like so:

Public Module RouteConfig

```
Public Sub RegisterRoutes(routes As RouteCollection)

    Dim settings = New FriendlyUrlSettings()

    settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off   'was permanent

    routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings)

End Sub
```

End Module

Then rename the Site.Mobile.master file to xSite.Mobile.master and also commented out the code in the ViewSwitcher.ascx.vb/cs file.

Not sure the last 2 steps are really necessary but I did them prior to the first one.

The result was friendly URLs and no redirection to the mobile master page.